# How to make parametric plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I wonder how to make multiple parameters in `pgfplot`? In the code I used `x` and `y` as parameters to draw sphere, with `radiuse 1cm`. When I added `x=2cm`, `y=2cm`, `z=2cm`, so that the plot would look better:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\tiny]
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle,     
    axis z line=middle,
    colormap/jet,            
    samples=40,              
    view={130}{30},          
    domain=-4:4,             
    y domain=-4:4,           
    restrict z to domain=-4:4,
    grid=both,
    xlabel={$x$},           
    ylabel={$y$}, 
    zlabel={$z$},  
    xmax=2,
    ymax=2,
    zmax=2,
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2,
    zmin=-2,
    xtick={-10,...,10},     
    ytick={-10,...,10},     
    ztick={-10,...,10},
    x=2cm,
    y=2cm,
    z=2cm,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=south,},
    every axis z label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=west,}
]
\addplot3 [
    samples=30,  
    domain=0:2*pi,
    y domain=0:2*pi,
] 
({cos(y*180/pi)*cos(x*180/pi)}, 
    {cos(y*180/pi)*sin(x*180/pi)}, {sin(y*180/pi)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately when I added them `view` function stopped working. How to fix the problem and draw grid only in `XY` plain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgfplots` manual has this warning!

> For three-dimensional axes, pgfplots computes a view direction out of
>   the provided unit vectors. The view direction is required to allow the
>   z buffer feature (i.e. to decide about depths)

on page 241, section 4.10 of version 1.11. Hence when you hange axis units, it will change the view angle.

If the idea is to enlarge, you can use `scale` key.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\tiny]
\begin{axis}[
   %x post scale=2,
%   y post scale=2,
%   z post scale=2,
    scale=2,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis z line=middle,
    colormap/jet,
    samples=40,
    view={130}{30},
    domain=-4:4,
    y domain=-4:4,
    restrict z to domain=-4:4,
    grid=both,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    zlabel={$z$},
    xmax=2,
    ymax=2,
    zmax=2,
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2,
    zmin=-2,
    xtick={-10,...,10},
    ytick={-10,...,10},
    ztick={-10,...,10},
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=south,},
    every axis z label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=west,}
]
\addplot3 [
    samples=30,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    y domain=0:2*pi,
]
({cos(y*180/pi)*cos(x*180/pi)},
    {cos(y*180/pi)*sin(x*180/pi)}, {sin(y*180/pi)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to draw grid only in XY plain?